# Is there any way to retrieve a steam CD key anywhere else than in the library screen?

Tags: steam, linux, dcs-world

DCS is the last thing I play that I haven't tried running on linux, if I manage to make it work, I'll finally be able to ditch Windows.

For those who don't know, DCS is a flight simulator, which uses a free-to-play platform as a base which includes the entire framework and two playable aircraft, more playable aircraft one buys as so-called modules, listed as DLC on steam.

DCS uses the old infamous Russian StarForce DRM, which requires you to activate a CD-key before playing your purchased modules. I have purchased some modules on Steam. The normal procedure of retrieving a CD-key on steam is simple, however, as far as I know, you can only do it from the Library screen. Since DCS is listed as a free game on steam, you can't access it in the library, unless you install it (or at least start installing it), which I can't, because Steam just plain refuses to install non-natively supported games on linux.

So. Has anyone ever found a way to retrieve the CD-keys without having the game in your library, yet having purchased it?

I'm interested in knowing whether there's a solution involving mostly steam. I could make a virtual machine, yes, or simply boot windows, but that's not the point of this question.

Comment: I think your best option is running steam in Wine

Comment: yes, I tried that, but it never worked for me. I asked this more or less to confirm that there is indeed no way to do this "legally", either as a feature of steam, or if there's at least a way to permanently have a free game in your library

But it does seem that I'm stuck with making steam work with wine (or wine work with steam?)

Comment: Afaik, free games stay in your library as long as you have them played and not removed manually, but it might be different where the game is not available on Linux

Comment: It's along the lines of a VM or Wine, but it is possible to [download an app from Steam for another platform/architecture](https://superuser.com/q/1597075/928285), and after that's started it should show in the Library. I tried digging into finding CD keys in the local Steam client data, but from what I recall found nothing useful, though it wouldn't be a great idea to share publicly if there was anything as thieves would use the information against users.